# Unable to fetch the accurate rooms availability in specific date range

Tags: php, mysql, database, join, mysqli

Here is my database structure

```
Table name :set_inventory, and columns are below
inventory_id | room_id | quantity_start_date | quantity_end_date | total_rooms
1            | 2       | 2015-10-10          | 2015-10-12 | 5
2            | 2       | 2015-10-13          | 2015-10-14 | 10
3            | 2       | 2015-10-15          | 2015-10-17 | 0
```

Another Table

```
Table name : rooms, amd columns are 
room_id | room_type | room_picture | room_description
2       | standard  | pic_link     | demo description
```

Description: In inventory table admin able to set the inventory based on multiple date ranges.

My query:

```sql
SELECT rooms.room_id, rooms.room_pic1, rooms.room_type, rooms.maximum_adults,
  rooms.maximum_children, rooms.room_amenities,set_inventory.room_id,
  set_inventory.quantity_start_date, set_inventory.quantity_start_date,
  set_inventory.total_rooms
from rooms, set_inventory
WHERE rooms.room_id = set_inventory.room_id
  AND quantity_start_date <= '2015-10-11'
  AND quantity_end_date > '2015-10-13'
```

It shows me the inventory only 5, based in above query,

What i am looking for :actually, i am looking for the result,
for example my check_in_date "2015-10-11" and check_out_date is "2015-10-17"
In this i will be able to notify the customer that 
"room is only available for 4 days,

Plz help me , thanks

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

Try this `WHERE` condition:

```
WHERE rooms.room_id = set_inventory.room_id AND DATE(quantity_start_date) <= '2015-10-11' AND DATE(quantity_end_date) > '2015-10-13';
```

---

So, minding you want to have the amount of days between these to dates, your query should contain somwthing like this:

```
SELECT ABS(DATEDIFF(a1.start_date, a2.end_date)) FROM (
    SELECT quantity_start_date as start_date FROM set_inventory WHERE quantity_start_date <= '2015-10-11' ORDER BY start_date DESC LIMIT 1) a1, (
    SELECT quantity_end_date as end_date FROM set_inventory WHERE quantity_end_date > '2015-10-13' ORDER BY end_date ASC LIMIT 1) a2;
```

If you try it, you'll get `4` in result.

Comment: its shows emplty result set, my need is is, if my total rooms set to zero in specific date interval, i just want to notify the customer that room is not available on this date

Comment: With your base request I have an empty set. I get the line with only `5` when I remove the `quantity_end_date` condition...

Comment: @rbstack, I've updated my answer. Is this the thing you would like to see in your result?